# Can't run the flutter app after added firebase-core and auth to the project

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Here's the error in console, plus flutter doctor didn't showed any error. I've tried upgraded the android sdk to 28, check build.gradle. It still don't work and I have no clue.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BjJ4.png)

Pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: ^1.1.1
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its AAPT issue;
Open this open  **C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\Flutter\eLesson\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml** and remove *`style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`*

and
your App or some of you plugin is not compatible to AndroidX. Open android folder of your project in separate Android Studio. Right click on Project->Refactor->Migrate to AndroidX.

Repeat this process for each of your plugin folder.

Clean and Rebuild.

Enjoy.

Comment: Sorry for my dumb question but what is AndroidX? I also use VS code instead of Android Studio

Comment: at first you follow the step of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64712775/5830240.

Comment: please read this Medium link you will get to know. https://medium.com/flutter-community/solving-androidx-error-in-flutter-89bdc45885a6

Comment: it said No Usages Found in the Project

Comment: Paste your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: pfft. My bad, I've accidently put those packages in dev-dependcies. Sorry and thx for your reply.

Comment: Hm, but the error still appeared. I've pasted the .yaml in the post.

Answer (score 2):

1- Move them to dependencies

2- Leave a space at the beggining of the dependencie name like so:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    
  firebase_core: ^0.5.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.2
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
```

If you realize, it's like if flutter and the rest of your dependencies were at the same level